# Anarchy Online in wine on Mac?

Tags: macos, wine, anarchy-online

Anarchy online doesn't have a Mac client so I'm wondering if it will run in `wine`.  I don't want to run it in bootcamp, and I don't quite feel like running it in a VM since I have to reset afterwards anyways.

Answer (score 4):

A friend of mine has made good experiences with running it with wine under Linux and [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org) gives it a "Gold" rating.

Comment: I managed to get the install to work, but I haven't tried playing just yet

Comment: And? Did you get it to work yet?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works. There are several How To's: look under Tech Help on the AO forums.

Or you could try [this](http://forums.anarchy-online.com/showpost.php?p=5932593&postcount=47) :)